# Why does my logic app timeout on some moments

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[image]

I have a logic app (Consumption)

As you see in the image, there are some connectors, of which the first is an azure function that should return a 200 Ok with a json response.

In the last step, the logic app should return a 202 (and continue working) containing a value from the previous Json.

As you see the Return steps goes into an error because of a time-out, but when I check the times (in the corners of the connectors) I don't see this timeout-values (when adding them together)

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that before the Azure function is called, there are numerous variables initialized, which can take up to 5/6 seconds each... Don't know why this would take so long just to init a variable, but it sees to explain my issue.